# Octave error when resizing rgb image

Tags: image, octave, rgb

I am trying to resize an image (rgb) using `imresize` , but it always gives this error

`error: imresize: IM must be a grayscale or RGB image.`

The image was loaded and displayed successfully using `imread` and `imshow`, with class `uint8`.

During debugging inside `imresize` i noticed that `isimage` inside the if condition is always = 0:

```
function im = imresize (im, scale, method = "cubic")

  if (nargin < 2 || nargin > 3)
    print_usage ();
  elseif (! isimage (im) || (! isrgb (im) && ! isgray (im)))
    error ("imresize: IM must be a grayscale or RGB image.")
.
.
.
```

And inside `isimage`, `ismatrix` was the reason for this to happen.

So i removed `ismatrix` from the condition because from the documentation it gives 1 only if the input matrix is 2D. And it is working, but i think this is not the best solution. Here is `ismatrix` after modification:

```
function retval = isimage (img)
  retval = (! issparse (img) && ! isempty (img) && 
            isreal (img) && (isnumeric (img) || islogical (img)));
endfunction
```

So any one has a better idea on how to solve this issue?.

EDIT:
Here is the code i was trying to run

```
  im = imread(pos(i).im);
  padx = model.sbin * widths(i) / pixels(2); ##some calculations
  pady = model.sbin * heights(i) / pixels(1);
  x1 = round(pos(i).x1-padx);
  x2 = round(pos(i).x2+padx);
  y1 = round(pos(i).y1-pady);
  y2 = round(pos(i).y2+pady);
  window = subarray(im, y1, y2, x1, x2, 1);
  warped{i} = imresize(window, cropsize, 'bilinear');
```

Subarray.m

```
% B = subarray(A, i1, i2, j1, j2, pad)
% Extract subarray from array
% pad with boundary values if pad = 1
% pad with zeros if pad = 0

dim = size(A);
B = zeros(i2-i1+1, j2-j1+1, dim(3));
if pad
  for i = i1:i2
    for j = j1:j2
      ii = min(max(i, 1), dim(1));
      jj = min(max(j, 1), dim(2));
      B(i-i1+1, j-j1+1, :) = A(ii, jj, :);
    end
  end
else
  for i = max(i1,1):min(i2,dim(1))
    for j = max(j1,1):min(j2,dim(2))
      B(i-i1+1, j-j1+1, :) = A(i, j, :);
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: loop over the third dimension

Comment: it's not clear what the problem is? `imresize` should be able to handle normal rbg images fine. Perhaps show a testcase of the relevant code you're using and a link to the image you're trying to resize?